# A weighted measure of international diversity

Tags: statistics, information-theory

Suppose that you are a company manager and you are looking for a statistical measure that defines the international reputation of your company. So, you collect data on your clients and the countries they come from.

You want this measure to have the following properties:

1- The more the number of countries where your client come from, the more your company is international.

2- If all of your clients are from a single country, i.e the number of countries is 1, your international reputation should be the lowest value. (let's say 0 for convenience)

3- Unfortunately, you have to discriminate between the countries on your client list. For business reasons, you prefer to have more clients from high-income countries and fewer clients from low-income countries and there are countries that you can't deal with because of sanctions, embargoes or similar reasons.

Let's say you have the following data:

1- $N$: The number of countries where your clients are from.

2- $p_i$: The fraction of your clients that come from the i-th country.

3- $w_i$: The desirability of dealing with clients from the i-th country.

I am currently reading about Rényi entropy as a potential method. Rényi entropy of order $q$ is given by the formula
$$^qH = \frac{1}{1-q} \ln(\sum_{i=1}^{N}p_i^q)$$
And I'm thinking of modifying it to a new formula taking "desirability coefficients" $w_i$ into account. My suggestion is this
$$^qH = \frac{1}{1-q} \ln(\sum_{i=1}^{N}w_ip_i^q)$$

Do you think this is a valid method? Are there any better methods or suggestions available?

Comment: Why not just literally weight the countries?  Thus, a person from country $A$ might count as $1.5$ observations, while another from country $B$ might be just $.8$ of an observation, or whatever weighting function you like.

Comment: I assumed you had a measure you were comfortable with, except for the weighting function.  For the dispersion, what's wrong with variance?  Low variance means high dispersion.  In some situations, people play with exponents (variance measures squared distance from the mean, you can use the fourth power or higher if you want to punish outliers more).

Comment: What do you mean "ordinal data"?  I would reweight the actual data (your method retains the old mean).  Thus, if I valued country $A$ twice as much as $B$, and my data was "two users from $A$ and four from $B$", I'd recast it as "four users from each" and thereby get a variance of $0$ (maximal dispersion).

Comment: In your formula I assume that $\mu_i$ meant $\mu$, the mean of the data.  As to "ordinal", if you have no numerical data I don't think statistics is going to help you.  If you have "subjective" data of some sort (maybe the notion that "country $B$ is lagging expectations while $C$ is still behind $A$ but catching up fast!" or something like that ) then you can change that into something quantifiable (subjectively, sure, but it's something).  But if you have no quantifiable information at all, then I really don't understand what it is you are asking.

Comment: @lulu: I have completely rephrased and rewritten my question. Now it looks more like a math problem. I hope you could clearly see what I'm looking for this time.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of a "valid method"?

Comment: @celtschk: A formula that takes into account only the parameters I introduced and satisfies all the properties I mentioned. One problem with the formula I suggested is that if $N=1$ and $w_i<1$ then it can become negative. The freedom in choosing such a formula is too much I think. People can come up with other formulas probably and I'm asking if there's one that is used more common and used more often in the literature.

Comment: Your "property 3" is not a mathematical property, in that it is not clear to check whether a candidate formula satisfies it. Note that the usual entropy is maximized when $p_1=p_2=\cdots=p_n$. Maybe you want your weighted entropy to be maximized when $p_1/w_1 = p_2/w_2 = \cdots = p_n/w_n$?

Comment: @Rahul: Why can't we check it? Can't we say that the candidate formula should be an increasing function with respect to $w_i$'s? The idea of the formula attaining a maximum is actually very useful and I think yes, it's a very reasonable property to consider.